# Not an ActiveMQ Artemis Destination exception4

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ibm-mq, activemq-artemis

I have Java application with Spring that runs on Jboss server 7.0 . I'm trying to integrate it with IBM mq adapter I've deployed wmq.jmsra.rar adapter and configured it as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        wmq.jmsra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/jms/MQConnectionFactory" tracking="false" pool-name="mq-my-app">
                            <config-property name="hostName">127.0.0.1</config-property>
                            <config-property name="port">1414</config-property>
                            <config-property name="channel">SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN</config-property>
                            <config-property name="transportType">CLIENT</config-property>
                            <config-property name="queueManager">MQ1</config-property>
                            <config-property name="username">admin</config-property>
                            <config-property name="password">passw0rd</config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/jms/MQRequestQueue" pool-name="queue-req">
                            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">MQ1</config-property>
                            <config-property name="baseQueueName">DEV.QUEUE.1</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                        <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/exported/jms/MQResponseQueue" pool-name="queue-res">
                            <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">MQ1</config-property>
                            <config-property name="baseQueueName">DEV.QUEUE.2</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

My IBM Server runs on docker and is acessed by localhost address.

In my java app with Spring context I'm accessing mq queues by jndi on app startup and when I'm trying to send message I get following error:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bankAdapterImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Not an ActiveMQ Artemis Destination:com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy@4d1be475; nested exception is javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Not an ActiveMQ Artemis Destination:com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy@4d1be475
```

Edit:
The way I'm accessing with jndi

```
 public static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY_NAME = "jboss/exported/jms/MQConnectionFactory";

 public static final String REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME = "jboss/exported/jms/MQRequestQueue";

...
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        return (Destination) jndiContext.lookup(REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME);
...
```

Comment: Have you reviewed https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/deploy_the_websphere_mq_resource_adapter ?

Comment: Here is another (Doug posts here so maybe he can help more): https://developer.jboss.org/thread/243515.  Can you show how you reference the jndi?

Comment: I've added jndi part

Comment: Should that be `java:jboss` instead of just `jboss` in the jndi reference?

Comment: It makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got what was wrong, I was using another jms template object that was using default Artemis Mq client instead of the one I accessed by jndi.